# Get last save date of excel document in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Today,I got badly stuck in getting excel last save date.Its not modified date.Any help would be highly appreciated.I was trying following code for last save date instead of created date but I couldn't make it work.Could anybody confirm that below method worked for them?

```
DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass oleDocumentPropertiesClass = new DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
oleDocumentPropertiesClass.Open("C:\\My Documents\\MyExcelFile.xls");
MessageBox.Show(oleDocumentPropertiesClass.SummaryProperties.DateCreated.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it without using the Office library, by checking the last-modified date of the file in the file system:

```
using System.IO;
var time = new FileInfo(@"C:\My Documents\MyExcelFile.xls").LastWriteTime;
```

Comment: yes ,it works for modified  date but not for last save date of excel.You can check last save date of excel in properties.

Comment: File system dates are unreliable at best. For one, they're based on the local time of the computer, which can vary if you move the file around, but also can be modified by other things, or, as the OP says, not modified even if the file changes.

Answer (score 3):

Using the excel interop assembly

```
var workbook = new Application().Workbooks.Open(@"somePath.xls", ReadOnly: true);
var lastSavedDate = (DateTime)workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties["Last Save Time"].Value;
```

[Full list of properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.builtindocumentproperties?view=excel-pia)

> Title
>   Subject
>   Author
>   Keywords
>   Comments
>   Template
>   Last Author
>   Revision Number
>   Application Name
>   Last Print Date
>   Creation Date
>   Last Save Time
>   Total Editing Time
>   Number of Pages
>   Number of Words
>   Number of Characters
>   Security
>   Category
>   Format
>   Manager
>   Company
>   Number of Bytes
>   Number of Lines
>   Number of Paragraphs
>   Number of Slides
>   Number of Notes
>   Number of Hidden Slides
>   Number of Multimedia Clips
>   Hyperlink Base
>   Number of Characters (with spaces)